# C++ difference between array of structs and equal arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, struct

Is there any difference in memory usage / execution speed between e.g.

```
struct test
{
   int a;
   float b;
   char c;
}; 

test ar[30];
```

and

```
int arr1[30];
float arr2[30];
char arr3[30];
```

? Lets pretend, that we are not talking about work comfort or programmer sided things, only speed of execution / memory usage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Yes, there can be a difference in performance, but it heavily depends on the usage case (as always). The best way to know: measure your use case.

Answer (score 8):

In terms of memory usage definitely.

When you allocate `test ar[30]` you are actually allocating:
int - float - char - (padding) - int - float - char - ...

While in your second example you are allocating:
int - int - int - .... - float - float - ... - char - ...

So the layout in your memory is completely different, which will have an impact on your performance (depending on what you do OFC)

Answer (score 2):

In term of execution performance (speed), there is a difference because of the [CPU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache); even if you ask the compiler to optimize.

If all the members of a given structure are accessed nearly together, the locality is increased, and you get less cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of memory size, the compiler may add padding to the struct to align memory, so it is possible that sizeof(test) > sizeof(arr1) + sizeof(arr2) + sizeof(arr3)